# What are the Build Settings for a Universal iPhone and iPad Application

Tags: iphone, ipad

What would be the settings to build and have accepted an universal app for both the iPad and iPhone?

That is, what would be the settings in Project X Info > Build for

- Architectures [ARCHS] ("Standard(armv6)" or "Optimized(armv6 armv7)" or other)
- Valid Architectures [VALID_ARCHS] ("armv6 armv7" or other)
- Build Active Architecture Only (checked or unchecked)

and what would we select in the dropdown (Device - 3.2|Distribution|armv?) ?

We're either getting warnings at build time that we haven't built for armv7, or the app upload is rejected on account of

> "The binary you uploaded was invalid.  When supporting iPhone, the executable must include support for the armv6 architecture".

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

This site gives a good information how to make a universal binary.

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/04/converting-iphone-apps-to-universal.html

Answer (score 2):

almost the same question, and I answered myself.

> [How to start a project with both outputs iPhone & iPad ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657968/how-to-start-a-project-with-both-outputs-iphone-ipad/2658070)

maybe can help someone

Answer (score 0):

For Universal you want:

- iPhone OS 3.1.x
- Architectures to armv6 and armv7

For more details on the topic check the [TUAW Dev Clinic](http://www.tuaw.com/2010/03/26/dev-clinic-submitting-apps-for-ipad-saturday/). click on the play button to review the chat discutions of the dev clinic for ipad.