# How to start a project with both outputs iPhone & iPad?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, project

Using the Pre Release Xcode 3.2.3 I get this as a Startup Project

[image]
<sub>(source: [balexandre.com](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2010-04-17_1155.png))</sub>

What should I chose / do to great a project that can have both iPad and iPhone as a target (**not showing the iPhone App on iPad** but a real iPad View)?

Thank you.

---

To avoid problems:

- **iPhone OS 3.1.3** is the latest release on iPhone
- **iPhone OS 3.2** is the latest release on iPad

My question **does not infringe any agreements that me and Apple are bound to**, as my question is regarding those already public Releases.

I just stated that on my Operating System I'm running the Xcode 3.2.3, that is all.

Comment: That information is under NDA by Apple. You shouldn't ask public questions regarding it, nor may anybody here legally answer questions about it.

Comment: @Claus, running iPad and iPhone is PUBLIC as you can do that already with iPhone 3.1.3 and iPad 3.2, I just stated that my XCode is 3.2.3 version! As KennyTM states, 3.2 is Released to public (it's the iPad OS) !!!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547315/what-are-the-build-settings-for-a-universal-iphone-and-ipad-application

Comment: The latest public version of Xcode is 3.2.2, pre-release Xcode 3.2.3 is not public

Comment: no matter what version of XCode is, the question is regarding the Universal Output not that this XCode is more/better than the others!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

just found out a simple way:

[alt text http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2010-04-17_1242.png](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2010-04-17_1242.png)

[alt text http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2010-04-17_1241.png](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2010-04-17_1241.png)

Then, if you want to switch to XIB files per device, let's say, the MainView for iPhone is A and the MainView for iPad is B, in your AppDelegate you add this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // The default have the line below, let us comment it
    //MainViewController *aController = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainView" bundle:nil];

    // Our main controller
    MainViewController *aController = nil;

    // Is this OS 3.2.0+ ?
    #if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 30200

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
            // It's an iPad, let's set the MainView to our MainView-iPad
        aController = [[MainViewController alloc] 
                              initWithNibName:@"MainView-iPad" bundle:nil];
    else 
            // This is a 3.2.0+ but not an iPad (for future, when iPhone runs with same OS than iPad)
        aController = [[MainViewController alloc] 
                              initWithNibName:@"MainView" bundle:nil];

    #else
        // It's an iPhone (OS < 3.2.0)
        aController = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainView" bundle:nil];
    #endif

    // Let's continue our default code 
    self.mainViewController = aController;
    [aController release];

    mainViewController.view.frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame;
    [window addSubview:[mainViewController view]];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: you don't need that `#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 30200` crap. As long as you use Base SDK 3.2, `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()` will work correctly on pre-3.2 devices

Answer (score 0):

You can choose the Application Type as "Universal" .

Comment: if you take a better look and the question, it's more how to upgrade an existing iPhone App to an Universal one.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I will go with you for that.