# How to create an Universal Binary for iTunes Connect Distribution?

Tags: build, app-store-connect, universal-binary

I created an app **that was rejected** because Apple say that my App was **not showing the correct iPad window** and it was showing the same iPhone screen but top left aligned.

Running on simulator, I get my App to show exactly what it should, a big iPad View.

my app as Apple referees that is showing on device:

[alt text http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2010-04-22_0939.png](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2010-04-22_0939.png)

my app running the simulator (50% zoom only):

[alt text http://cl.ly/cCH/Screen_shot_2010-04-22_at_09.40.24.png](http://cl.ly/cCH/Screen_shot_2010-04-22_at_09.40.24.png)

my code in the Application Delegate is the one I [published before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657968/how-to-start-a-project-with-both-outputs-iphone-ipad)

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // The default have the line below, let us comment it
    //MainViewController *aController = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainView" bundle:nil];

    // Our main controller
    MainViewController *aController = nil;

    // Is this OS 3.2.0+ ?
    #if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 30200

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
            // It's an iPad, let's set the MainView to our MainView-iPad
        aController = [[MainViewController alloc] 
                              initWithNibName:@"MainView-iPad" bundle:nil];
    else 
            // This is a 3.2.0+ but not an iPad (for future, when iPhone/iPod Touch runs with same OS than iPad)
        aController = [[MainViewController alloc] 
                              initWithNibName:@"MainView" bundle:nil];

    #else
        // It's an iPhone/iPod Touch (OS < 3.2.0)
        aController = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainView" bundle:nil];
    #endif

    // Let's continue our default code 
    self.mainViewController = aController;
    [aController release];

    mainViewController.view.frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame;
    [window addSubview:[mainViewController view]];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

on my target info I have **iPhone/iPad**

[alt text http://cl.ly/cwB/Screen_shot_2010-04-22_at_09.33.12.png](http://cl.ly/cwB/Screen_shot_2010-04-22_at_09.33.12.png)

**My question is**, how should I build the app?

- Use Base SDK
- iPhone Simulator 3.1.3
- iPhone Simulator 3.2

my Active Configuration is `Distribution` and Active Architecture is `arm6`

Can anyone that already published app into iTunes Connect explain me the settings?

**P.S.** I followed the Developer Guideline on `Building and Installing your Development Application` that is found on `Creating and Downloading Development Provisioning Profiles` but does not say anything regarding this, as I did exactly and the app was rejected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it turns out that, after sending the project to Apple Support they reply saying that could be a mistake, that I should recompile and send it again.

Done that, and got my [App aproved](http://itunes.apple.com/dk/app/superoffice-usec-calculator/id368381350?mt=8).

But I can just tell here, how you should compile your app to the AppStore (Apple Review Team) from the email I got from **Apple Developer Technical Support**

---

Follow these steps to build a universal application that will run on both iPad and iPhone:

- Set the Base SDK build setting (in the Architectures section)  to iPhone SDK 3.2.
- Set the iPhone OS Deployment Target build setting to iPhone OS 3.1.3 or earlier.
- Set the Targeted Device Family build option to iPhone/iPad.
- Make sure that your Architectures build setting uses both armv6 and armv7.
- Set the Active SDK to iPhone Device 3.2, select your Distribution configuration, build (select the Build button) your application, and submit it for App review.

---

I hope this helps someone as it helped me :)

---

**Added (specify the Icons for both apps)**

[alt text http://cl.ly/11AF/Screen_shot_2010-05-10_at_15.37.51.png](http://cl.ly/11AF/Screen_shot_2010-05-10_at_15.37.51.png)

As you can see for the image above, just add a new property called `CFBundleIconFiles` and add the 2 icons, the Array (0) is for iPhone Icon, the Array(1) is for iPad icon.

Remember to leave the default `Icon file` property to the iPhone for back compatibility with old versions of the OS.

remember to specify the correct sizes for both apps:

- **iPhone icon**: 57 x 57 pixels
- **iPad icon**: 72 x 72 pixels

Comment: What did you do for the icons for iphone and ipad?

Comment: you just edit the pList... I will add this in the answer as well, give me 5 minutes