# Problem with uploading to appstore: wrong icon size

Tags: iphone, ipad, itunes

I'm having a problem uploading my app to the Apple App Store. It is saying that my icon/image size for iPad is too small. The size in the build is 52x52 and it is supposed to be 72x72. How can I resolve this?

My app is for both the iPhone and iPad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check the [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480563/how-do-i-specify-both-icons-for-a-universal-iphone-ipad-app) [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689012/how-to-create-an-universal-binary-for-itunes-connect-distribution) [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876336/is-it-possible-to-make-my-iphone-apps-icon-look-correct-on-both-the-ipad-and-iph)

Answer (score 1):

Add a `CFBundleIconFiles` key of type Array to your `Info.plist`. The array should contain 2 string items: the filenames of the two icons. The OS will then automatically choose the correct icon for each platform based on their pixel dimensions.

You can keep the `CFBundleIconFile` key and have it point to the icon file for the iPhone for 3.0/3.1 compatibility.

For more details go through http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/

Answer (score 0):

Use my git hub repo with all the image sizes in to start from :

https://github.com/FattusMannus/iOS-Development-Image-Placeholders

Hope this helps

AH