# Project Conversion - iPad to iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, ios

So I am trying to convert an iPad project to an iPhone project.  This is backwards from what most people are doing, and I was wondering if there was an easy way to do this, or will I have to rebuild/redesign all my views myself.

It wouldn't be that big of a deal to redesign the interface, but naturally, if there was an easier way, I would love to explore it.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of guides that explain the opposite (iPhone -> iPad) and they will also help you here since the steps and problems are basically the same. You will end up with files that can be shared and files that you need in an iPhone and iPad version.

Comment: Interesting, so all of this data is stored in one project, and then is decided on at install time?  Or does the whole thing get installed and determined at run time?  I know you can check the device and launch a different app delegate depending...

Comment: There are two possibilities: either compile to two different apps, one for iPhone, one for iPad. But the more elegant is to only have one app which serves both and which files to use is decided at runtime. [Here's a document from Apple](http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/resources/introductiontouniversalapps.pdf), but there are plenty of guides out there. Search for "universal app". You'll also find lots of material on SO, like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657968/how-to-start-a-project-with-both-outputs-iphone-ipad/2658070).

Comment: See also [this article](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/04/converting-iphone-apps-to-universal.html). As I said, the steps are more or less the same when you come from an iPad instead of an iPhone app.