# Code Base or Project for both iPhone and iPad - Is having one project or 2 project advisable

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5

I am a starter and learnt objective-c two months ago and developed an iphone application using storyboard & ios 5.1. I want to replicate the same functionality on iPad with almost similar screens (scaled to ipad). I see having one project can help me share most header and implementation files.

But will it affect performance. Is it advisable to have a seperate code base for ipad. My iphone app performance is currently good. I might have little more added functionality for iPad. What are your experiences. Please share.

Thanks

Comment: Good questions, these are legitimate and important things to consider. Stack Overflow probably isn't the right place to ask, though; these are broader, higher-level and more discussion-y issues that we typically like. You might want to try Programmers SE, or a traditional forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One project will be a lot more manageable in the long run. This post has some advice that might be relevant for your project:

[How to start a project with both outputs iPhone & iPad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657968/how-to-start-a-project-with-both-outputs-iphone-ipad/2658070#2658070)

Answer (score 1):

Use 1 project, 1 code base and 1 repository. This is how we do all our projects and Apps.

There are not many differences between the two UIs and when you DO want to take advantage of iPad Controls not available on iPhone it is easier to simply test for device type and invoke the appropriate control. Well designed Apps will in most cases need the rest of the surrounding logic in both.

If you diverge your code it is going to get messy with you having to replicate everything you do TWICE for the most part and try to keep all the logic threads coherent. DON'T DO IT. You will regret it, and it simply is not worth it to save a few bytes.

Comment: Thanks cliff & user1509593. This is for small business (Enterprise store not to sell for App store). End of day, performance matters.  agree with maintenance. Having 2 repositories is always problem. I worked in siebel and during multiple projects, we had multiple repositories and no matter what, somebody, somewhere will miss update in one. However, will loading a bloated universal app affect performance. Any ideas The iPhone app or iPad app will have just presentation layer or front end. All calls are through REST API to backend server

Comment: Most apps are built the way I described, including Apples. There will be a moderate size difference but very likely NOT a performance difference.

Comment: @CliffRibaudo: AFAIK, iOS builds for different devices will have different sets of graphics (e.g. there's no point having 2x graphics on a 3GS). I don't know if the app binaries are different; most of the frameworks are the same apart from armv6 vs armv7. Similarly, it *might* be worthwhile having different iPhone and iPad *targets* within the same project that share the same code for size reasons, but I really wouldn't bother until this was known to be an issue.